Why does Cognito's admin-get-user report that a user does not exist if it is external user?
There is a user, let's say, user@email.com whom I can see in AWS Cognito Console. But when I try to access that user using admin-get-user, I get UserNotFoundException. Here is a python code of what I was trying to do:
import boto3

# Initialize the Cognito client with the specified profile
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='Profile_Name')
client = session.client('cognito-idp', region_name='us-east-1')

# Get the user details
try:
    response = client.admin_get_user(
        UserPoolId='user-pool-id',
        Username='user@email.com'
    )

    # Extract the email and creation time
    email = response['UserAttributes'][2]['Value']
    created_at = response['UserCreateDate'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    # Print the user details
    print(f"Email: {email}, Created At: {created_at}")
except client.exceptions.UserNotFoundException:
    print("User not found")

The output of the above code is User not found.

Thinking it might be that cognito sdk filters external users, I experimented with list-users. The code was able to easily get the user. Here is what the code looked like:
import boto3

# Initialize the Cognito client with the specified profile
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='Profile_Name')
client = session.client('cognito-idp', region_name='us-east-1')

# Get all users in the user pool
user_info = []
pagination_token = None

while True:
    # Get users with pagination
    if (pagination_token != None):
      response = client.list_users(
          UserPoolId='user-pool-id',
          AttributesToGet=['email'],
          PaginationToken=pagination_token
      )
    else:
      response = client.list_users(
        UserPoolId='user-pool-id',
        AttributesToGet=['email'],
      )

    # Extract the emails from the response
    for user in response['Users']:
      # print(user)
      user_info.append({
          'email': user['Attributes'][0]['Value'],
          'created_at': user['UserCreateDate'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
      })

    # Check if there are more users to fetch
    if 'PaginationToken' in response:
        pagination_token = response['PaginationToken']
    else:
        break

print("List of emails and creation times:")
for info in user_info:
    print(f"Email: {info['email']}, Created At: {info['created_at']}")

# Check if the specified email is in the list
target_email = 'user@email.com'
is_email_present = any(info['email'] == target_email for info in user_info)

# Print the result
print(f"Email {target_email} is present: {is_email_present}")

The weird thing here is that admin-get-user's doc says that it should work on any user:

Gets the specified user by user name in a user pool as an administrator. Works on any user.

I need help on solving this problem. Otherwise, I would have to use list-users to fetch all users just so that I can get details about a user that I want.

For users from an external provider, the username that works for me in admin_get_user is f"{identity provider ID}_{email}". It can also be seen in the username in the list of users in AWS Console's Cognito.
